# Button to toast when listView selector isn´t there. Android

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, selector, toast

I think I have not made myself clear on what I´m trying to achieve.

I have a listView:

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    </ListView>
```

As you can see, this list view includes a listSelector that highlights the item selected on the list once clicked.

Now, Im trying to program a button to display a toast message when this list1 has no selector on it, (when no item in there has been selected and highlighted in gray) and to set the visibility of a website layout to visible when it does.

something like:

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
    If (list1.selector == null){
    toast("no item selected in list1")
    } else {
    website.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

For reference here are my codes:

```
val nameofanimals = arrayOf("cat","dog","parrot")

internal lateinit var adapteranimals: ArrayAdapter<String>
```

my adapter:

```
adapteranimals = ArrayAdapter(
    this@MainActivity,
    R.layout.list1layout,
    nameofanimals)
list1.adapter = adapteranimals
```

thank you in advance for your support

Regards

Comment: Did my answer provide a solution?

Comment: No, it keeps showing the toast message. I kinda solved it by using the websiite url instead of the list view, since once you select an item it loads an specific url, so if my webviewer has no url loaded, it shows the toast, if it does, it changes the visibility. I just couldn´t find a way to make it work from the lisview, thank you anyway Derek!

Answer (score 0):

I would create an [**`Extension`**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html):

```
fun ListView.hasSelector(): Boolean {
    for (i in 0 until this.count) {
        if (this.isItemChecked(i))
            return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Then call it in the `clickEvent`:

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
    If (!list1.hasSelector){
        toast("no item selected in list1")
    } else {
        website.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```